# TCPDF Displaying data from database (mysql)

Tags: php, html, sql, database, pdf

This is the first time that I have used a PDF generating PHP plugin(?). Anyway, I have this code in which I do not see any output from writeHTMLCell I have not idea why. But whenever I output this MySQL code in a normal PHP file it outputs properly.

```
$htmlhead ='<!--some css formatting and header here-->';

$htmlfooter = '</table>';

$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM request"); 
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $htmlbody ='
    <tr>
    <td>'.$row["ID"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["ServiceType"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["serOthers"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["State"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["UnitType"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["utothers"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["Purpose"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["property_no"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["Req_By"].'</td>
    <td><img src='.$row["signfile"].' width="200" height="82"></td>
    <td>'.$row["Division"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["D_n_T"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["dtAcc"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["Act"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["Status"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["Acc_By"].'</td>
    </tr>
    ';
          }


$pdf->writeHTMLCell($htmlhead . $htmlbody . $htmlfooter, true, false, false, false, '');

$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: Debug it.  Comment out the entire $htmlbody code and add just one line.  try it out.  The add the second,  try it out, ...  One like is could contain something writeHTMLCell does not like.  Or print the HTML and make sure it is valid before sending it to writeHTMLCell (no missing tags, `"`, ...)

Comment: @Nic3500 I tried printf-ing the whole table and it showed me a table. But it's not appearing on the pdf itself. Thank you though!